# GIF will not load first frame in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, gif

I have created a GIF and put it into my eblast. It works in a web browser as well as Gmail. However, it does not work in Outlook. Through my research, I understand that Outlook will not show a GIF. Instead, it is supposed to automatically show the first frame of the GIF. In my experience, it is not showing anything in Outlook. When I open the eblast in Outlook, I can tell that an image is supposed to be there and since I paired it with a link, the mouse hovers over a clickable blank space.  I am so confused and do not know if I am doing something wrong?  Here is my piece of code:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="bordertext">
            How do you provide your patients with quality patient education materials?
            <br><br>
            <a href="https://www.understand.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://email.understand.com/understand/template/logo_animated.gif" width="100%" alt="Understand.com">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

WOW! I fixed my own issue. Change width from 100% to px. For some reason, Outlook was shrinking it down to the faintest line (almost undetectable). It works now and I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

it's good to see you worked out your issues. I wanted to mention something in case others are looking for solutions to animated gif issues with Outlook.

Since Outlook will not display beyond the first frame, create the first frame to have all of the elements you hope to display. Even if set the time delay to instantaneous, Outlook will show it and other email clients will blow right buy it.

The best thing is to make your final frame become frame 1, but sometimes that is not always possible, but it will cut down on the size of the animated gif image as opposed to adding one more frame.

Good luck.